# .NET MAUI and python scripts

Tags: python, android, .net, maui

I have a Xamarin Android project. In this project  i'm running a python script using IronPython. The problem is that IronPython does not allow complex scripts and import sections (for example, "import random" will cause an exception).

If I migrate the project to MAUI, are there any improvements in this regard? Or any other options?

Comment: There is no connection between migrating from Xamarin Android to Maui, and use of IronPython. The two are not related. Microsoft does not have any Maui-specific recommendation re Python. And recommendations are out-of-scope for StackOverflow. Search `use python with .Net`, and see what you can find on the web. Any solution won't be specific to Maui; Maui runs on .Net. Find some .Net solution for each platform you want to run on. If you attempt to use some solution you find, and get stuck, create a new question here. Link to doc or library you use. Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add more IronPython libraries, check out this discussion on adding pip install for IronPython and then you should be able to install more libraries using the command line.

https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/pip-install-for-ironpython/106631